# showing jQuery is not defined even though jQuery file loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am working on angular.js application in that I have loaded jQuery file still it shows error message

**Error**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ popup.js:1

**Files loaded**

```
<script type="text/javascript"src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/appCtrl.js"></script>
```

I am not getting when is this popup.js is from.

Can anyone suggest me how to get rid of this error?

Comment: popup.js is loaded before jQuery (possibly in the head of your document). That's what's causing the error. When on your website, open the developer tools and press ctrl+F and typ "popup". Maybe you'll find the file.

Comment: @BramVanroy In my application I didn't load any popup.js

Comment: Well apparently your console tells you you did. Do what I said, check your source code on the page. Press search and look for it.

Comment: In console error is coming from popup.js but it was not in app directory . Here is that file https://gist.github.com/NilapuAnusha/3902f2b482b2d1f17538

Comment: What file is that. What are you linking to. If console can refer to a popup.js file it *has* to be there. No question. Upload your HTML somewhere so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Move the jquery js reference to head tag or above the popup.js reference.

Comment: I am not including any popup.js

Comment: @AnushaNilapu, In visual studio press control + shift + F and search popup.js. I am sure popup.js should be in somewhere.

Comment: @AnushaNilapu, Then in firefox, press Control + U (View Source) and search

Answer (score -2):

If you are working in laravel then add your CSS and Javascript file in index instead header and footer

Comment: They said they were using Angular, so the odds of them using laravel (at least for the purposes of serving the document that hosts the SPA) are minute.